# Handling Refresh Token

Tags: .net, ajax, security, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api that uses OWIN Authentication in my ASP.NET WebAPI and I need to implement refresh token.

When users login, API sends a `Access_Token`, `Expiry_Date`(3 mins) and `Refresh_token` to client.

Then the tokens are saved in the client `localStorage`.

I know that the use of refresh_token is to get new `access_token` if the `access_token` is expired.

Now my problem is *When to do this?*

Do i need to check if the client still has a valid/un-expired `access_token` EVERY TIME i request for a data in the Web API? And if the access_token is expired, i need to request a new access_token right?

For example:

1. Client (Mobile hybrid app) request for data in `api/orders` (Web API).
2. The client detected that the `access_token` he uses is expired base on the `Expiry_Date` that was saved in the localStorage.
3. I need to "STOP" the request, get new `access_token` using `refresh_token` and then request the `api/orders` again. Basically doing THREE requests simultaneously? Seems to me a bit in efficient.

Or get the user to login again? I mean every 3 minutes the user needs to login? Which defeats the purpose of this.

Any idea how to handle it?

In this sample ajax request below, can someone have idea handle this?

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: WEB_API_URL,
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
         // need to check if the accessToken is expired
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
       },
   }).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first get the tokens from your datastore. Check if they are valid for the next few seconds also. You don't want to run into a failed authorization because your request is delayed by something.

If the token is going to expire soon, use your refresh token to get new access token.

Then send your request to the Web Api.

In short;

```
1. Get token from datastore.
2. Check if token is valid.
3. If not valid, get new token.
4. Send request to Web Api.
```

I have no experience with Ajax, but with this flow you should be able to handle your request with a maximum of 2 request to your api.

Comment: 1-3 is done in login, what about if the client is already logged in. do we need to 1-3 again? and it gets complicated if the token is invalid in time of request to webapi

Comment: the thing is, MY point is when the user log in, it's token is stored in localStorage, then in the succeeding request to API, it will use this token. What if the token expires when the user is already logged in? In my case, i have my token expiry in 3 Minutes.

Comment: That's why you need to retrieve the token from your datastore for every request. Any else you are not able to make requests after 3 minutes anymore. I don't know the specific background, but maybe increase the expiration time if you want to reduce the amount of calls for new tokens?

Comment: you mean I need to request a new access_token every request? what do you mean by datastore? My implementation is, when the user login, I get the access_token from the web api then save it in localStorage in the client. Every request to the API, I use this access_token from localStorage.Now the problem arise when this token expires. Thats my problem whats the next step?.

Comment: By datastore, I mean your local storage. When it is expired or going to be very soon, use your refresh_token to retrieve a new access_token from Web Api. Store the new access_token in your localStorage again.

Comment: ok so it is simulataneous? before any request to web api, I need to check if the current token expired? if expired - request for a new token, then do the API request again, just like what I mentioned in number 3 in my post? 2 simultaneuos request?

Comment: Actually thats what I exactly doing, i just thought there would be a better way

Comment: BEcause im having problem in multiple assynchronous query requesting for a new token simultaneously.

Comment: In my example Ajax request above, how can we do that?